# can't change NSTextField text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I have a problem with NSTextField - that I **can't change the text** in it (can change it once, in *(void)awakeFromNib*, but not after that).

I'll give you my header and implementation here:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Employee.h"


@interface EmployeeView : NSViewController {  
    NSTextField *mikk;  
    Employee *employee;  
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *mikk;  
@property (retain) Employee *employee;

- (void)setSelectedEmployee:(Employee*)employeeIn;

@end


#import "EmployeeView.h"


@implementation EmployeeView

@synthesize mikk, employee;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil  
{  
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];  
    if (self) {  
        // Initialization code here.  
    }  

return self;  
}  

- (void)setSelectedEmployee:(Employee*)employeeIn  
{  
    employee = employeeIn;  
    NSLog(@"given employee = %@", employee.fullName);
    [mikk setStringValue: @"hi"];  
}  

-(void)awakeFromNib  
{  
    NSLog(@"i awoke");  
    [mikk setStringValue:@"hello"];
}  

- (void)dealloc  
{  
    [employee release];  
    [mikk release];  
    [super dealloc];  
}  

@end
```

It may look f-d up, but the main point is that I call the method

```
- (void)setSelectedEmployee:(Employee*)employeeIn
```

in my appDelegate and give it the "Employee" that's selected, thus the instance has an employee to work with. I know for sure, it gets the given employee, because *NSLog* always prints it out correctly.
The *NSTextField* called "mikk" is correctly linked in IB, cause it sets the labels text to "hello" in the *awakeFromNib* method. So the main problem is: **why I can't set the labels text elsewhere?**

I know this looks weird/stupid, but please let me know, if you'd like any more information (also what, if you can be more specific) and suggestions to make this text more readable.

**Edit**: Looked over the code and left only the "i-think-important-bits" in. Also retained the IBOutlet without any effect on the goal.

Comment: Have you set the `view` outlet, too?

Comment: @Caleb, sorry for leaving unnecessary stuff there, I was just too tired yesterday. And @Bavarious, I have connected the view in IB with the `NSViewController` (that's using custom class of `EmployeeView`). Should I make an `Outlet` for it in code also?

Comment: `NSViewController` already declares a `view` outlet, which you’ve said you’ve already connected. (For the record, `@` in comments notifies only the first user; in your comment, it notified Caleb but didn’t notify me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using garbage collection? Here's what the [docs on nib loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6) say about object retention under garbage collection:

> Most objects in the graph are kept in
>   memory through strong references
>   between the objects. Only the
>   top-level objects in the nib file do
>   not have strong references initially.
>   Thus, your code must create strong
>   references to these objects to prevent
>   the object graph from being released.

So, if you don't have a strong reference to the top-level object that contains your text view, probably a view or window, the entire object graph is probably being collected.

Comment: I am using garbage collection. If it changes anything, I have created an instance in my `appDelegate` of the `EmployeeView` and am using it there to call for it when needed.

Comment: Presumably `EmployeeView` is the view that contains the label in question? Are you creating it by loading it from the nib? Whatever the details, if you're calling `-setSelectedEmployee:` and the label that `mikk` points to doesn't change, then it seems likely that `mikk` is pointing to the wrong thing, or to nothing at all. Try looking at the value of the pointer in `-awakeFromNib` and then again in `-setSelectedEmployee:`. If it changes, then `mikk` is somehow being modified. If it doesn't, then the memory it points to is probably changing, deallocated, etc.

Comment: @Caleb, Yes, Yes, I added breakpoints to those methods and saw that on the second time it calls `-awakeFromNib` (the program calles it twice, is that ok?) the `mikk` is pointing to `0x0` (on the first call it had a valid memory address) and it stays `0x0` through the program.

Comment: @Mikk, if `mikk` is 0x0 (i.e. nil), then you probably forgot to connect it to a text field in you nib. I know you said its value is set to 'hello', but wondering if you didn't set that up in the nib as well? Also, if -awakeFromNib is called twice on the same class, it probably means that you're instantiating the class twice, which is not likely what you want in this case.

Comment: @Caleb, it's connected correctly in the nib, and changes it in the runtime (in nib it's title is "Label"), but I guess the underlying problem I have here, is that I make another instance of the class. Thanks for helping me to get to the right path.

Comment: @Mikk, it's starting to sound like a case of mistaken identity. It's not uncommon that someone instantiates a view or view controller twice by mistake, and then manipulates the wrong one and wonders why they don't see the change. Glad to hear you're back on track.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *mikk;
```

to

```
@property (retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *mikk;
```

Comment: This is the right answer. You're using an assign property for your outlet, so the text field is being released after it's loaded.

Comment: @Caleb Why would it be released?

Comment: @Bavarious, see my answer below. "collected" is probably a better word than "released," but I'm usually in an iOS mindset so I default to thinking in terms of retain/release.